# InstallShield 2009 - SdLogonUserInformation Problem (The list is empty.)

Tags: installshield

I need a setup created with InstallShield 2009 to install a windows service. The service needs an own account to be run under. This accounts needs to be created/selected from within the setup.

For this, I add the corresponding Logon Information Panel dialogs:
Dialogs -> All Dialogs -> *Right Click* -> New Dialog...

On the New Dialog Wizard:
*Next* -> Logon Information Panel and Associated Child Dialogs -> *Next* -> *Finish*

However, when I start the setup, and try to browse existing users, it does not matter whether i try to browse Domains, users or whatever, I always get a messagebox saying

"**The list is empty**.".

Detailed description:

- On the Login Information dialog, I click on *browse*
- On the Browse for a user account dialog, I click on *browse* for the domain or server -> Result: **The list is empty**.
- On the Browse for a user account dialog, I enter the name of the server I am on into the Name of server textbox and click on *browse* for the user name --> Result: **Server not found**
- On the Browse for a user account dialog, I enter Administrator into the User name textbox while having the name of the server still entered into the Name of server textbox and click on *OK* --> Result: "**Server not found**"
- After clicking *Cancel* (back in the Logon Information dialog), I enter SERVERNAME\Administrator into the User name textbox and the corresponding password into the Password textbox and click on *Next* --> Result: **Server not found**
- I click on *New information*
- I click on *Browse* for the Domain or Server --> Result: **The list is empty**.
- I click on *Browse* for the groups --> Result: **Server not found**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

There are so many people having problems with that dialogs it's almost ridiculous that Acresso failed in providing support for this.

However, the solution is simple: 
For browsing anything like groups or users, ISNetApi needs the servername. For the servername to be verified or browsed, it needs the ComputerBrowser service.

And guess what... the ComputerBrowser service is disabled on Windows Server 2008 by default (and on other OS versions as well).

In case you really want to enable it, you will need to also enable Printer and File Sharing from within the Network And Sharing Center (because the ComputerBrowser service depends on them).

Comment: ComputerBrowser on Windows 2008 R2 enabled and it worked like a charm .. BUT, consider to wait for 2-3 minutes!